# Access To Font "font url" from Origin "Url" has been blocked CORS error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

Hello I've had a good look around and can't find an answer.

The error is pretty clear but the solution is not.

The custom font is not loading. I have the custom font under `assets/fonts/TypoGraphica.eot`

Below is the error:

[image]

font.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family:"TypoGraphica";
  src:  font-url("TypoGraphica.eot?") format("eot"),
        font-url("TypoGraphica.woff") format("woff"),
        font-url("TypoGraphica.ttf") format("truetype"),
        font-url("TypoGraphica.svg#TypoGraphica") format("svg");
}

.typographica { font-family: $font-typographica; }
```

Here is my cors. At the moment I am allowing any requests:

```
module Taddar
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end

    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
    config.browserify_rails.commandline_options =
      '-t [ babelify --presets [ env react stage-0 ] --plugins [ syntax-async-functions transform-regenerator ] ]'
  end
end
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by having the adding the following to `assets.rb`

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/`

Answer (score 0):

From another source

For my fellow sufferes, here's how I eventually solved the issue. The problem wasn't the gem itself, the problem was that the stack didn't provide a OPTIONS route, like any other framework outside of ruby does automatically (wth?) If you're used to work with Java or something similar, this probably hits you unprepared.

So, adding these route in the routes.rb solves the issue:

```
  # global options responder -> makes sure OPTION request for CORS endpoints work
  match '*path', via: [:options], to: lambda {|_| [204, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }]}
```